# Pasting objects between files in Indesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6

I just upgraded from CS4 to CS6 and am having an issue pasting objects between files in InDesign.

Seems like the issue is with the styles. I'm copying a basic graphics frame but it is losing the image and rounded corners while applying a stroke to the frame.

Shouldn't the characteristics of the copied object carry across? Anyone know how to overwrite or force InDesign to paste objects 'as is' regardless of what styles a file may have?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. There was some style on the original document that needed clearing before pasting. The joys of working with other people's documents...